# Install failed: "SuiteSparseQR.hpp: No such file or directory"

Tags: software-installation, dependencies

I want to install a program that requires (among other things) SuiteSparse.

I installed SuiteSparse   -> no errors,

typed "cmake ."           -> no errors

then "make"               -> *[./././.]*/build/../include/Array2D.h:38:48: fatal error: SuiteSparseQR.hpp: No such file or directory

Does anyone know why? If it was not installed during the install of SuiteSparse, can/should it be installed separately?

Comment: How exactly did you install SuiteSparse?

Comment: Downloaded the v4.5.3 .tar.gz,  extracted into the Downloads folder (using the GUI), then navigated to that folder in the terminal window and ran $ make, and then $ make install. There was a lot that scrolled past, if there was an error in there I missed it. There was nothing in the final lines to suggest it hadn't installed ok. Is there a way to check?

Comment: Ran what? Your fundamental issue seems to be that the files are not installed in a 'standard' location where the compiler knows to look for them. Did you know there is a `libsuitesparse-dev` package that you can install direct from the main repository? Unless you are sure you need v4.5.3 that would almost certainly be a simpler route for you.

Comment: I didn't know, but when I check my package manager it says it's installed. Could it be a problem with the program not being able to find it? I'm running Mint, and I think the program was written for Ubuntu. The makefile and CMakeLists don't mention suitesparse, so how could I point it to the right place, wherever that is? (BTW, if you've not guessed, I'm new to all this so BIG thanks for the pointers!)

Answer (score 2):

The actual location is `/usr/include/suitesparse/SuiteSparseQR.hpp`

The `Array2D.h` file assumes the location `/usr/include/SuiteSparseQR.hpp`

**To solve the problem,**

1. Open the file `../include/Array2D.h` in a text editor.

   ```
   nano ../include/Array2D.h
   ```
2. Find the line

   ```
   \#include "SuiteSparseQR.hpp"    // for in-paint
   ```
3. Change it to

   ```
   \#include "suitesparse/SuiteSparseQR.hpp"    // for in-paint
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question and answer when I tried installing `SuiteSparse` [from source](https://people.engr.tamu.edu/davis/suitesparse.html) as the OP does and after running-

```
make
sudo make install
```

In the extracted SuiteSparse folder and manually installing the dependencies using `apt-get install  libgmp3-dev libmpc-dev` I still got the error

```
suitesparse.hpp not found
```

When I tried to compile a project that used SuiteSparse. I couldn't easliy figure out the path mismatch issue specified in the comments and the answer by @Bhageera but when I ran

```
sudo apt-get install libsuitesparse-dev
```

The project managed using `cmake` and `make` began to compile.